# EF Code First Development in Team Envinronment

Tags: ef-code-first

We are developing a code first application. Everyone uses the same test database. The `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` is used.  The configuration is as below.

> AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
>
> AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;

But when someone makes a change in the model, other people in the team has the old version of the code and get error. They must update the code to run the project. How can I solve this problem? Should everyone use local database?

Comment: Developers should _always_ work with a local database. Not just because of code-first development. There are many other ways to screw up a database (structure of content) during development. You don't want to impede a whole team when that happens.

Comment: in addition to Gerts comment(+1).  by definition, code and DB definition go together with code first. So you either centralise the POCO model or decentralize the DB during the development phase.

Comment: Very thanks, I will decentralize the db in development environment, and centralize in the test environment.